# What type of complexity is "builder.replace"?

Tags: java

I'm doing the stairCase puzzle on HackerRank and a guy mentioned that it can't be solved for less than o(n^2). The link for the puzzle: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase/problem

I solved it using nested loops but another guy posted the following solution:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) 
        builder.append(" ");
    int j = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++) 
{
        builder.replace(builder.length()-i,          
        builder.length() - j, "#");
        System.out.println(builder);
        j++;
}
```

and I'm wondering is it o(n^2) as well ? is builder.replace going through all the string just like a for loop ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: By the way, OpenJDK is open-source, and you can [read the source code for the `replace` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.replace%28int%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%29).

Comment: @chrylis thanks so much for the link. I will bookmark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `builder.replace` will use an native array copy call which has `O(n)` complexity. So with the outer loop, it is `O(n^2)` overall. Because the output has length `O(n^2)` then any program that produces it will have at least that time complexity.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. Is it true that it can't be solved for less than O(n^2) ?